# Array CompareFind Equals words only using array not array list

Tags: java, arrays

**Have a two text file with words list. need save both file in two array.I know how to do it using list and set.. but here I want know how to do it using only arrays.Only array and no predefined functions such as Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort() can be used

no list no ArrayList or no class from Java Collection Frameworks can be used.**

```
public class Main {
public static Set<String> setlist1= new HashSet<>();
public static String[] arrayList=new String[file1count];
public static String[] array2=new String[file2count];
public static int file1count=0;
public static int file2count=0;   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        /*read the files*/
        Scanner rf= new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new          FileReader("D:\\IIT\\Project save\\New\\Inteli J\\OOPworkshop01\\file1.txt")));
        Scanner rf2= new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\IIT\\Project save\\New\\Inteli J\\OOPworkshop01\\file2.txt")));
        String line;
        String line2;


        while(rf.hasNext()){
            line=rf.nextLine();
            file1count++;
        }

        while(rf2.hasNext()){
            line2=rf2.nextLine();
            file2count++;
        }

        rf.close();
        rf2.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        BufferedReader reader1 =
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\IIT\\Project save\\New\\Inteli J\\OOPworkshop01\\file1.txt"));

        BufferedReader reader2 =
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\IIT\\Project save\\New\\Inteli J\\OOPworkshop01\\file2.txt"));

        String line1 = reader1.readLine();

        String[] array1 = new String[10000000];
        String[] array2 = new String[10000000];

        String line2 = reader2.readLine();

        boolean areEqual = true;

        int lineNum = 1;

        while (line1 != null || line2 != null) {
            if (line1 == null || line2 == null) {
                areEqual = false;

                break;
            } else if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) {
                areEqual = false;

                break;
            }

            if (line1 != null) {
                array1[lineNum] = line1;
            }
            if (line1 != null) {
                array2[lineNum] = line2;
            }

            line1 = reader1.readLine();

            line2 = reader2.readLine();

            lineNum++;
        }

        if (areEqual) {
            System.out.println("Same content.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("different content");

        }

        reader1.close();

        reader2.close();
```

You can simply try above code.

Here I had used only `WHILE` loop, `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`.

Comment: And how to save this words to array

Comment: @Chathuranga Why you want to save that words in array??
You just want to compare two files and that's it.

Comment: If one line contain one word then automatically it will give you equal line from both files.

Comment: No. I have to use that array for another thins.. only i need to know when programme reading the file save all word in 2 array. File1 and file 2

Comment: Then i can do what ever i needed

Comment: Yes.one line contain one word

Comment: @Chathuranga You can try updated answer.
Here i am considered you have max 10000000 as you don't want to use **Arraylist or any other collections**

Comment: thnx for your anws. But I only need to save to array and after i can check equal word or what ever i like.. Because i add one part of my program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using arrays is that you don't know in advance what length to allocate.

You basically have two options:

- read each file twice
- allocate an array of some initial length, and reallocate is as needed (that's what an ArrayList does.)

Second option: let's have a method readFile that reads all the lines from a file and returns an array:

```
public static String[] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        String[] lines = new String[10]; // start with 10
        int count = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (count >= lines.length) {
                lines = reallocate(lines, count, 2*lines.length);
            }
            lines[count++] = line;
        }
        if (count < lines.length) {
            // reallocate to the final length;
            lines = reallocate(lines, count, count);
        }
        return lines;
    }
}

private static String[] reallocate(String[] lines, int count,
        int newLength) {
    String[] newArray = new String[newLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        newArray[i] = lines[i];
    }
    lines = newArray;
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Fine. where is storing part.. I think it's too compilicated.. This is not what i want i think

Comment: @Chathuranga probably not: just use what's available.